# No Source Available for current location while connecting to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

Hi i am getting following error while trying to connect to a database

> Locating source for 'e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {43 28 d1 1d 5d 3b a6 a8 15 e d3 6b 52 f5 4d 89}
>   The file 'e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
>   The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file 'e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Sql\SqlDatabase.cs'.

my we.config entry is

```
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=version;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;Connect Timeout=300;User ID=myusername;Password=mypass"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You're getting an error, and the debugger is trying to throw up the sourcecode where the (likely) exception occurs. Since it's a pre-compiled Enterprise Library block, it can't find it. Try stating the exception instead?

Comment: add some breakpoints on your code and then step through each step so you can identify where the error comes from..

Comment: Where is the file **SqlDatabase.cs**??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the references to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary are correctly configured. Check their paths. Try adding and re-adding the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary references in your project, make sure they point to the same library.